# <iframe> not displaying pages from the same site, but displaying pages from another site

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, iframe, x-frame-options

I am deploying an `<iframe>` on a page on **Site A** as a quick and simple way to display a fragment from a complex page elsewhere on **Site A**:

```
<iframe src="http://site-a.com/complex-page/"></iframe>
```

Nothing displays in the `<iframe>` on **Site A**.

## Troubleshooting:

1. I checked `http://site-a.com/complex-page/` in the browser and the page displays normally.
2. I tested the `<iframe>` by using `http://site-b.com/complex-page/` as the source and the `<iframe>` displays the external page on (external) **Site B**, as expected.
3. I tested the `<iframe>` by using `http://site-a.com/complex-page-2/` as the source and, once again, nothing displays in the `<iframe>`.

So... this is clearly something to do with **Site A**, if the `<iframe>` on **Site A** is not displaying any of several pages on **Site A**, *but it is showing any of several pages* on **Site B**.

This clearly isn't a *same-origin* issue - **Site A** *is* the same origin as **Site A**.

So what is preventing the  displaying of the external page on **Site A**?

**Additionally:**

If I `Right Click > This Frame > View Frame Source` then I *can* see the HTML Source of the document loaded by the `<iframe>`... but whatever content or styles I add to the document, nothing displays.

That suggests the `<iframe>` is successfully accessing the page but then (for some reason) failing to display it.

---

**Supporting information:** *The site is built with PHP server-side and with HTML5, CSS3 and Javascript client-side.*

Comment: Aha. Progress. I've just discovered this on `Firefox Developer Tools > Console >  JS`...: _Load denied by X-Frame-Options: `http://site-a.com/complex-page/` does not permit framing._

Comment: I've just tried inserting `<meta http-equiv="X-Frame-Options" content="allow">` into the `<head>` of the source page, but that hasn't worked.

Comment: did you define a width and height for the iFrame?

Comment: Thank you, Johannes - I hadn't but I didn't imagine it would make much difference. I've tried adding the attributes now and as I suspected, it makes no difference. This is definitely an `X-Frame-Options` issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem was a little easier to solve, once I had understood that what I was facing was an `X-Frame-Options` issue.

Apparently `X-Frame-Options` can have three values:

- `DENY`
- `SAMEORIGIN`
- `ALLOW-FROM` [URI]

`X-Frame-Options` can be set in an `.htaccess` file using any of the three values above.

In this case I needed to add **the following lines** to my `.htaccess` file:

```
# HEADERS
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
Header set X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN"
</ifModule>
```

---

Thanks to this page:

**[Iframe] X-Frame-Options : website does not permit framing**

http://techdc.blogspot.co.uk/2015/04/iframe-x-frame-options-website-does-not.html

Comment: Also be aware that Google Chrome does not accept the X-Frame-Options header. you must configure Content security policy

Comment: I've just tested the page in Chrome 60 and it's working fine (for now). Thank you for the heads up. I'll keep it in mind.